# Transaction commit throwing exception: Transaction set to rollback only

Tags: jakarta-ee, transactions, websphere, jta, atomikos

My application is trying to do a distributed transaction on 2 databases on a DB2 server, app server is websphere 6.1 and using Atomikos as the TM.

UserTranaction.commit() is failing with the following exception: 
*javax.transaction.RollbackException: Transaction set to rollback only*
The full stack trace is:

```
    [3/26/12 12:08:43:880 EDT] 0000001f SystemErr     R javax.transaction.RollbackException: Transaction set to rollback only
[3/26/12 12:08:43:896 EDT] 0000001f SystemErr     R     at com.atomikos.icatch.jta.TransactionImp.rethrowAsJtaRollbackException(TransactionImp.java:70)
[3/26/12 12:08:43:896 EDT] 0000001f SystemErr     R     at com.atomikos.icatch.jta.TransactionImp.commit(TransactionImp.java:250)
[3/26/12 12:08:43:896 EDT] 0000001f SystemErr     R     at com.atomikos.icatch.jta.TransactionManagerImp.commit(TransactionManagerImp.java:498)
[3/26/12 12:08:43:896 EDT] 0000001f SystemErr     R     at com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionImp.commit(UserTransactionImp.java:129)
[3/26/12 12:08:43:896 EDT] 0000001f SystemErr     R     at com.Servlet.InitialServlet.doPost(InitialServlet.java:131)
[3/26/12 12:08:43:896 EDT] 0000001f SystemErr     R     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:763)
[3/26/12 12:08:43:896 EDT] 0000001f SystemErr     R     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
[3/26/12 12:08:43:896 EDT] 0000001f SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1101)
[3/26/12 12:08:43:896 EDT] 0000001f SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:569)
[3/26/12 12:08:43:896 EDT] 0000001f SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
[3/26/12 12:08:43:896 EDT] 0000001f SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3440)
[3/26/12 12:08:43:896 EDT] 0000001f SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:267)
[3/26/12 12:08:43:896 EDT] 0000001f SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:815)
[3/26/12 12:08:43:896 EDT] 0000001f SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1461)
[3/26/12 12:08:43:896 EDT] 0000001f SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:118)
[3/26/12 12:08:43:896 EDT] 0000001f SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:458)
[3/26/12 12:08:43:896 EDT] 0000001f SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:387)
[3/26/12 12:08:43:896 EDT] 0000001f SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:102)
[3/26/12 12:08:43:896 EDT] 0000001f SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
[3/26/12 12:08:43:896 EDT] 0000001f SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
[3/26/12 12:08:43:896 EDT] 0000001f SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
[3/26/12 12:08:43:896 EDT] 0000001f SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:136)
[3/26/12 12:08:43:896 EDT] 0000001f SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:195)
[3/26/12 12:08:43:896 EDT] 0000001f SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:743)
[3/26/12 12:08:43:896 EDT] 0000001f SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:873)
[3/26/12 12:08:43:896 EDT] 0000001f SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1473)
[3/26/12 12:08:43:896 EDT] 0000001f SystemErr     R Caused by: com.atomikos.icatch.RollbackException: Transaction set to rollback only
    at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.TxRollbackOnlyStateHandler.commit(TxRollbackOnlyStateHandler.java:84)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.CompositeTransactionImp.doCommit(CompositeTransactionImp.java:319)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.CompositeTerminatorImp.commit(CompositeTerminatorImp.java:79)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.jta.TransactionImp.commit(TransactionImp.java:236)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.jta.TransactionManagerImp.commit(TransactionManagerImp.java:498)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionImp.commit(UserTransactionImp.java:129)
    at com.Servlet.InitialServlet.doPost(InitialServlet.java:131)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:763)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1101)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:569)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3440)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:267)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:815)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1461)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:458)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:387)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:102)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:136)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:195)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:743)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:873)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1473)

[3/26/12 12:08:43:896 EDT] 0000001f SystemErr     R     at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.TxRollbackOnlyStateHandler.commit(TxRollbackOnlyStateHandler.java:84)
[3/26/12 12:08:43:896 EDT] 0000001f SystemErr     R     at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.CompositeTransactionImp.doCommit(CompositeTransactionImp.java:319)
[3/26/12 12:08:43:896 EDT] 0000001f SystemErr     R     at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.CompositeTerminatorImp.commit(CompositeTerminatorImp.java:79)
[3/26/12 12:08:43:896 EDT] 0000001f SystemErr     R     at com.atomikos.icatch.jta.TransactionImp.commit(TransactionImp.java:236)
[3/26/12 12:08:43:896 EDT] 0000001f SystemErr     R     ... 24 more
```

I have NOT set the transaction to rollback only in the code. I guess its set by default.I want to change it and not set it to rollbackOnly. Also, I am explicitly calling commit() after the transaction. Why is it that i am still getting this exception? How do i ensure that the transaction gets committed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue!!
Here is what worked for me:

1. Open the Web Deployment Descriptor
2. Select the Servlet which initiates the transaction.
3. For the Servlet, seletec the Websphere Extensions > Local Transaction.
4. Set the Resolver as "ContainerAtBoundary" and Unresolved Action: Rollback.
5. Save and RePublish.

Voila...I can commit the transaction now!!